# "NOTICE AUTH" notifications when connecting to IRC server

Tags: python, irc, rfc

As a learning exercise, I'm writing a Python program to connect to a channel on an IRC network, so I can output messages in the channel to stdout. I'm using asynchat and manually sending the protocol messages, rather than using something like Twisted or existing bot code from the net - again, it's a more useful learning experience that way.

I can send JOIN and USER commands quite happily, and can PING/PONG away as required. However, I've noticed when opening a socket to port 6667, I'll receive some messages:

```
NOTICE AUTH :*** Looking up your hostname...
NOTICE AUTH :*** Checking ident
NOTICE AUTH :*** Found your hostname
NOTICE AUTH :*** No identd (auth) response
```

even if I've not yet sent the JOIN/USER commands.

So, is this opening sequence of notifications specified anywhere? As far as I can see, the RFC doesn't specify for anything in particular to happen before the client sends the JOIN command, and I wasn't sure whether to wait for receipt of these notices before sending the JOIN command, and if so how do I detect that I've received all of the notices?

Comment: Hrm, I meant NICK wherever I typed JOIN above. Obviously channel joining happens later in the game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no RFC requirement to do this, it's just a common thing that servers in the wild do. Observe that they're plain old NOTICE commands (i.e. just messages). Just treat them as messages sent to a psuedo-user "AUTH" (since the server doesn't have a better name for you yet). You're not required to wait for them, and the server is not required to send them.

Comment: They're actually from the server (because no sender prefix was specified), and sent *to* an entity called "AUTH".  The server's calling you that because you don't have a nick yet.